# How to delete a remote git commit HEAD?

Tags: git, github

I messed up a lot of code with git merge and also lost my work in the process.

I am in this situation:

- commit `A` - I pulled this from the remote first and merged.
- commit `B` - I pushed the merged commit..
- commit `C` - I still had some merge conflicts, so i merged again and pushed.

Now the remote contains commit `C` as `HEAD`. It is totally flawed and also, I lost my code. The only way I can solve this is I want to delete the commit `B` and `C`. Revert to commit `A` and do the work again.

Kindly, let me know if there is a SAFE way to delete the commit `B` and `C` without messing up other commits? Suggest other solution if possible.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this:

http://lrotherfield.com/blog/delete-remote-git-repo-to-specific-commit/

STEP 1 : For resetting head locally,(consider A as the commit id)

git reset --hard A

STEP 2 : For resetting head in the remote

git push -f origin A:master

Finished..

Now my commits B and C are deleted from the remote and the head points to A.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout commit A, create a new branch out of it, and then push this branch and use it in future.

Basically, do:

- `git checkout A` You will be in a detached state right now
- `git checkout -b new_branch` Verify all your changes are there as needed
- `git push origin new_branch`

Now you can continue working on this new_branch.

In case you need to overwrite the older branch itself, you have two options

- Either force push your branch in the last step above using

  - `git push origin new_branch:old_branch_on_origin`
- Or reset the HEAD on branch locally and force push it

  - `git checkout old_branch`
  - `git reset HEAD --hard A`
  - `git push origin -f old_branch`

The problem with the second approach above is that if some other developer has pulled in your changes and started working on them, the branch history on his machine could get out of sync because of the forced push.

Comment: I cannot reset HEAD to commit A, I get the error.. Cannot do hard reset with paths

Comment: Can you checkout the commit as mentioned in the first approach then? try it, and let me know the complete error trace in either case